# Select matching rows from a table where either one of two columns contain any value from a list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Could you please help me with a SQL query for the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database? I have a table structure like so:

```
User
----------------------
Id          int
UserName    nvarchar


Likeable
---------------------
Id          int
Name        nvarchar


UserLike
----------------------
Id          int
UserId      int
LikeableId  int


Book
-----------------------
Id          int
Name        nvarchar
Author      nvarchar
Description nvarchar
AmazonUrl   nvarchar
```

So, to get the names of things that a user likes, I use this query:

```
SELECT Name
FROM [User] u JOIN UserLike ul ON u.Id = ul.UserId
JOIN Likeable l ON l.Id = ul.LikeableId;
```

Let's call that query **Query 1**.

> Results of **Query 1**:

```
Name
----------
Python
C#
Kotlin
```

**What I want:**

Now, I'd like to return a **DISTINCT** result set of books, i.e. all the columns of the **Book** table where either the book name or the book description contains any of the words from the results of **Query 1**. This is where my SQL skills come to halt.

I'd like to use this query in a Java `PreparedStatement` so if you could just stick to using a regular query rather than any fancy data structures or stored procedures, that'll be great.

I'll be using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 as the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `JOIN` . . . but using `LIKE` or `CHARINDEX()` for the condition:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Book b JOIN
     (SELECT Name
      FROM [User] u JOIN
           UserLike ul
           ON u.Id = ul.UserId JOIN
           Likeable l 
          ON l.Id = ul.LikeableId
     ) n
     ON b.title LIKE '%' + n.name + '%' OR
        b.description LIKE '%' + n.name + '%';
```